# How to bind Dataset to DataGridView in windows application

Tags: c#

I have created Windows Application. In this, I have multiple tables in dataset, now I want to bind that to a single DataGridView. Can anybody help me?

Comment: I think you can check out [DataViewManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xz507ds%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

following will show one table of dataset

```
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds; // dataset
DataGridView1.DataMember = "TableName"; // table name you need to show
```

if you want to show multiple tables, you need to create one datatable or custom object collection out of all tables.

if two tables with same table schema

```
dtAll = dtOne.Copy(); // dtOne = ds.Tables[0]
dtAll.Merge(dtTwo); // dtTwo = dtOne = ds.Tables[1]

DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
DataGridView1.DataSource = dtAll ; // datatable
```

sample code to mode all tables

```
DataTable dtAll = ds.Tables[0].Copy();
for (var i = 1; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
{
     dtAll.Merge(ds.Tables[i]);
}
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
DataGridView1.DataSource = dtAll ;
```

Comment: Nice! Only thing that `DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns` is `true` by default unless someone has set it to `false` explicitly. You won't need to set it here to `true` again as shown in the code snippet above.

Comment: one question please with `AutoGenerateColumns` set to false can I do something like we do in `datatable` to `datagridview` so I can get value from`datatset` and assign to specific column in datagridview ?    `Mygrid.Columns["Mydridcolumn"].DataPropertyName = dt.Columns["SEQ"].ColumnName;`

Answer (score 6):

use like this :-

```
gridview1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; <-- Use index or your table name which you want to bind
gridview1.DataBind();
```

I hope it helps!!

Comment: But using this way we can bind only single table i want to bind all tables.

Comment: @sonal are all those tables having same schema?

Comment: @Damith yes all arehaving same schema

Answer (score 0):

you can set the dataset to grid as follows:

//assuming your dataset object is ds

```
datagridview1.datasource= ds;
datagridview1.datamember= tablename.ToString();
```

tablename is the name of the table, which you want to show on the grid.

I hope, it helps.

B.R.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me in asp.net

```cs
dgHistory.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; // dgHistory is the datagrid
  
dgHistory.DataBind();
```