# How to bind a dataset to datagrid

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to bind Dataset to DataGridView in windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099619/how-to-bind-dataset-to-datagridview-in-windows-application)

How do i bind a Data Set to a Data Grid View? and The data Set has already data rows on it. I just wanna bind it to a Data Grid.

Comment: There are 101 examples on line check out this link here 
[how to bind a dataset to a datagrid](http://www.google.com)

Comment: @DJKRAZE Yeah, he should have googled

Comment: i think not. my problem is iv'e already created an datatable and loaded some data on it from a class. and i want to retrieve all the data on that dataset in another Window Form..

Comment: All you do is `DataGridView1.Datasource = Form2.ds.Tables[0];` - make `ds` a public Dataset in Form2.

Comment: Iv'e tried this code but it wont work..... `DataSet ds  =  new DataSet();
            gridview.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            gridview.DataSource = ds.Tables["ReminderVehicle"] // dataset
            gridview.DataMember = "ReminderVehicle";`

Comment: @JesunBicar No offense, but if you quality help show code, errors you have gotten, etc. Thats from the FAQ on how to post questions.

Answer (score 3):

I would have to say that this is ALMOST a duplicate question and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099619/how-to-bind-dataset-to-datagridview-in-windows-application) is the answer.

For example:

```
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True;
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds; // dataset
DataGridView1.DataMember = "TableName"; // table name you need to show
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you can vote to close - then someone with > 2K or 3K will  approve it.

Comment: i think not. my problem is iv'e already created an datatable and loaded some data on it from a class. and i want to retrieve all the data on that dataset in another Window Form..

Comment: @JeremyThompson I said ALMOST