# Outputting SQL results to gridview using stored procedure is not binding

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Following on from my previous question, I now have a basic app which updated a record in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database upon providing the 3 variables and clicking a button.

I now wish to add a feature whereby once the record has been updated, it displays the result to my gridview that I have added to the form. Named `gridSelectID`. I have a basic stored proc named `viewclassdata` at db level which takes `@ID` as a parameter and brings back rows which only relate to this.

In terms of C# Heres what I've got so far:

```
//execute the command 'cmd', the profile class will now be updated at db level
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //Once the Profile Class change has been committed, show the results in the gridview
                var selectcmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.viewclassdata", conn);
                selectcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                selectcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                SqlDataAdapter oAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectcmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                oAdapter.Fill(ds);
                gridSelectID.DataSource = ds;
                //gridSelectID.DataBind();
```

I had to comment out `gridSelectID.DataBind()` as it was throwing up an error, I've since read that the `DatBind()` method is not required for win forms.

I have run in debug mode and although the program still updates the db perfectly, it is not outputting the newly updated information to my gridview as I would like. Can anyone see where i'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not outputting the new information to my gridview as I would like"? Is it possible to be more specific?

Comment: I mean the code you cannot see is updating the record as I wish, but then the code above is not bringing back the new row(s) once the records have been updating. Its not bringing anything back in fact.

Comment: I supose you have run the proc with th ID in sql and return the disered result? Also check the ds if it has Tables in it

Comment: Yes the SP brings back what I expect in SSMS, and yes the DS has all the tables and SP's listed

Comment: Try gridSelectID.DataSource = ds.tables[indextableyouwant2show];

Comment: Or add gridSelectID.DataSource = ds; gridSelectID.DataMember = "YourInsertNewRowTable";

Comment: has the same resuls. I mean you see that your datatable X from your dataset Z has rows and you set it as datasource of your grid and does not bring anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the conn in the second parameter like this:-

```
SqlDataAdapter oAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectcmd,conn);
```

Comment: There is no meaning of that. conn is passing it to command. I mean it is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should check two things:

1. First you need to check if your stored procedure is returning data
   or not.
2. Check [how to bind DataSet to DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099619/how-to-bind-dataset-to-datagridview-in-windows-application).