# vb.net to pull data from Excel Data GridView

Tags: excel, datagridview, vb.net-2010

I have **78** excel columns and I have **5** datagridviews.

How do I make connection?

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want to achieve, but to get the maximum out of any answer, it would be better if you add some code or some further explanation.
For example how should anyone know which excel data should be displayed in DataGridView one, two etc...

Anyway, i would recommend that you divide the task into two steps:

ReadExcel and DisplayData. In my opinion reading data from excel file via OLEDB is a good way to start. Therefore i recommend reading the following article: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/705470/Read-and-Write-Excel-Documents-Using-OLEDB

For displaying the data in a DataGridView you need to bind a dataset to it. Maybe you´ll find the following post helpful:

[How to bind Dataset to DataGridView in windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099619/how-to-bind-dataset-to-datagridview-in-windows-application)

Its both c# code, but i think getting things running for vb.net is an easy task.

Edit: I found some older vb.net of mine you can use. It´s not that good piece of code but it should get you started. It imports the whole data of an excel sheet. But please don´t just copy and run :)

```
Public Shared Function ImportExcelSheetData(ByVal ExcelFilePath         As String, _
                                          ByVal SourceExcelSheetName  As String, _
                                          ByRef pDestDataTable        As DataTable, _
                                          ByRef ErrMsg                As String, _
                                          Optional ByVal WithHeader   As Boolean = False) As Integer

Dim ConnectionString      As String   = ""
Dim WithHeaderString      As String   = ""
Dim nOutputRow            As Integer  = 0

Dim oleExcelCommand       As OleDbCommand
Dim oleExcelConnection    As OleDbConnection

ImportExcelSheetData = -1 ' Error by default

If System.IO.File.Exists(ExcelFilePath) <> True Then
  ErrMsg = "Error: File does not exist." + vbCrLf + "Filepath: " + ExcelFilePath
  Exit Function
End If

If WithHeader = True Then
  WithHeaderString = "Yes"
Else
  WithHeaderString = "No"
End If

ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ExcelFilePath + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=" + WithHeaderString + ";IMEX=1"""

oleExcelConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
oleExcelConnection.Open()

If IsNothing(pDestDataTable) = True Then
  pDestDataTable = New DataTable
End If


' if SourceExcelSheetName is not set, use first sheet!
If SourceExcelSheetName.Trim = "" Then
  Dim tmpDataTable As DataTable = oleExcelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,  Nothing)

  if IsNothing(tmpDataTable) OR tmpDataTable.Rows.Count < 1 Then
    throw new Exception("Error: Could not determine the name of the first worksheet.")
  End If

  Dim firstSheetName As String = tmpDataTable.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()

  If firstSheetName.Trim() <> "" then 
    SourceExcelSheetName = firstSheetName
  End If
End If

If SourceExcelSheetName <> "" Then

  Try
    Dim oleAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()

    oleExcelCommand = oleExcelConnection.CreateCommand()

    If SourceExcelSheetName.EndsWith ("$") = True Then
      oleExcelCommand.CommandText = "Select * From [" & SourceExcelSheetName & "]"
    Else
      oleExcelCommand.CommandText = "Select * From [" & SourceExcelSheetName & "$]"
    End If

    oleExcelCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    oleAdapter.SelectCommand = oleExcelCommand
    oleAdapter.Fill(pDestDataTable)
    oleExcelConnection.Close()

  Catch ex As Exception
    ErrMsg = Err.Description
    Exit Function
  End Try
End If

ImportExcelSheetData = 0  ' Ok
```

End Function

Comment: Hi, did the answer helped you?