# Fill a datagridview with specific XML node from several XML files

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I have to fill a datagridview with 3 specifics XML nodes data from several XML files.

Here it´s an example:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<retorno>
    <mensagem>
        <codigo>00001 - Sucesso</codigo>
    </mensagem>
    <alerta>
    </alerta>
    <numero_nfse>641</numero_nfse>
    <serie_nfse>1</serie_nfse>
    <data_nfse>08/09/2020</data_nfse>
    <hora_nfse>12:16:10</hora_nfse>
    <arquivo_gerador_nfse>688569.xml</arquivo_gerador_nfse>
    <cod_verificador_autenticidade>03379569</cod_verificador_autenticidade>
</retorno>
```

I need these get 3 tags - `<numero_nfse>`, `<data_nfse>`, `<cod_verificador_autenticidade>` - and load them into a datagridview.

However, there are more XML files, with the same tags and I would to load all of them at the same time into a datagridview.

I wrote the code bellow and as you can see, it´s not working.

```
string[] arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Documentos\retorno");
DataSet retorno = new DataSet();

for (int j = 0; j < arquivos.Length; j++)
{
    FileInfo Xmls = new FileInfo(arquivos[j]);

    string caminhoXmls = Convert.ToString(Xmls);

    XmlDocument retornoXml = new XmlDocument();
    retornoXml.Load(caminhoXmls);

    XmlNodeList retornoTags = retornoXml.GetElementsByTagName("retorno");
    foreach (XmlNode xn in retornoTags)
    {
        string XmlNumeroNfse = xn["numero_nfse"].InnerText;
        string XmlDataNfse = xn["data_nfse"].InnerText;
        string XmlHoraNfse = xn["hora_nfse"].InnerText;
        string XmlCodigo = xn["cod_verificador_autenticidade"].InnerText;
    }

    retorno.ReadXml(caminhoXmls);

    dgvDadosNota.DataSource = retorno.Tables[j];
}
```

To clarify: I want one column for each tag. So my datagridview would be with 3 columns and as many rows as there are files in the directory. There´s only one `<retorno>` in each XML file.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a (simplified) example of the XML you are trying to load -- i.e. a [mcve].  [`GetElementsByTagName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementsbytagname?view=netcore-3.1) is deprecated BTW: *It is recommended that you use the `XmlNode.SelectNodes` or `XmlNode.SelectSingleNode` method instead of the `GetElementsByTagName` method.*

Comment: Even better to use LINQ to XML.

Comment: You are using a `DataSet` with one `DataTable` for each file.  Is that what you really want to do?  Wouldn't it make more sense to use a single `DataTable` with 3 columns and one row for each XML file?  When you do `dgvDadosNota.DataSource = retorno.Tables[j];` you are overwriting the previous binding so of course you're only going to see one result.

Comment: My goal is to read every XML file on that directory, get the specifics tags inside each of and load them into the datagridview.

Comment: @AndréLuis - with one row for each file, and one column each for `<numero_nfse>`, `<data_nfse>` and `<cod_verificador_autenticidade>`?  Or could there be multiple `<retorno>` tags in each file?  Because you can't bind an entire `DataSet` to a `DataGridView`, you can only bind a specific `DataTable`.  See [How to bind Dataset to DataGridView in windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11099619).

Comment: one column for each tag. So, datagridview would be with 3 columns and as many rows as there are files in the directory. There´s only one <retorno> in each XML file.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading your multiple XML files into a `DataSet` with one `DataTable` for each file, but as explained in *[How to bind Dataset to DataGridView in windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11099619)* you can only bind a *single `DataTable`* to a `DataGridView`.

Since you have only one `<retorno>` node in each file, it would make sense to load the files into a `DataTable` with 3 columns - one each for `<numero_nfse>`, `<data_nfse>`, and `<cod_verificador_autenticidade>` - and one row for each file.

The following code does this:

```
static DataTable CreateDataTableFromRetornoXML(IEnumerable<string> fileNames)
{
    var columnNames = new []
    {
        "numero_nfse",
        "data_nfse",
        "cod_verificador_autenticidade",
    };
    var rootName = "retorno";
    
    var table = new DataTable();
    foreach (var name in columnNames)
        table.Columns.Add(name, typeof(string));
    
    foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
    {
        var row = table.NewRow();
        var root = XElement.Load(fileName);
        var retorno = root.DescendantsAndSelf(rootName).Single(); // There should be only one.
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            row[column] = retorno.Element(column.ColumnName)?.Value;
        }
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    
    return table;
}
```

Note I have switch to the [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview) API which is generally easier to work with than the old `XmlDocument` API.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1d5ctO).